# How can I transform an Excel formula to html/javascript with the outcome rounded to whole euros?

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have this formula

```
=IF( B2>3.5, (((B3*B1*1.4*12)/100))+((B1/3)*45*(B3*12/13/4/40)), (B1/3)*45*(B3*12/13/4/40) )
```

The outcome is in full euro's. Is it possible to round to whole euros? Like this with a point between the thousands and hundreds €25.962

Comment: Are you familiar with programming at all? You can use cell references (such as `B2`) as variables. `IF()` can be replaced with a regular `if()` statement or a ternary. The rest is all arithmetic and logical operators which are all present in JavaScript. I'll post an example as an answer, but it'd be useful to know whether you're familiar with programming or not.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I'm not that familiar with programming. If you could post an example I would be very happy.

Comment: I have 2 very important considerations: 1) [Read this post on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); 2: when you post formulas or code, be sure to wrap it in **backticks** - ` `like this` ` - because asterisks can count as markdown formatting. Note that the `45` in your formula got *italicized* because it was "surrounded" by asterisks. It took me a while to notice that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily translate elements of your expressions into programming:

- Cell references (such as `A1` and `ES44`) can be converted to [variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var);
- The `IF()` function behavior can be perfectly reproduced by using regular [`if/else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) blocks or a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator);
- [Arithmetic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators), [logical](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) and [comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) operators all have their respective counterparts in JavaScript.

As for getting the user's input, you can retrieve it watching for changes or submissions of [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) tags inside a [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) tag, then processing the data from the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) with `document` selection methods such as [`.getElementId()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and then using a previously set [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

#### Example

**EDIT:** Since you asked me in the comments, I formatted the output using [**Intl.NumberFormat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) (language-sensitive number format). I see you're located in Netherlands, so I used the default format for your region (ISO code `nl`).

```js
function analyzeData() {

  // declare variables with let keyword when inside a block scope (such as functions)
  // assign the value of element with ID b1 to the var b1
  let b1 = document.getElementById("b1").value;

  // assign the value of element with ID b2 to the var b2
  let b2 = document.getElementById("b2").value;

  // assign the value of element with ID b3 to the var b3
  let b3 = document.getElementById("b3").value;

  // declare a result var with initial value of 0
  let result = 0;

  // using an if/else block
  if (b2 > 3.5) {
    // result if b2 is greater than 3.5
    result = (((b3 * b1 * 1.4 * 12) / 100)) + ((b1 / 3) * 45 * (b3 * 12 / 13 / 4 / 40));
  } else {
    // result if b2 is lower than or equal to 3.5
    result = (b1 / 3) * 45 * (b3 * 12 / 13 / 4 / 40);
  }

  // populate the content of the h1 with the results
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = new Intl.NumberFormat('nl', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'EUR'
  }).format(result);

}
```

```html
<!--
  onchange *listens* for changes in the form, then
  triggers analyzeData(). A change is detected whenever
  the user presses enter or leaves an input (also
  known as a blur event).
-->
<form onchange="analyzeData()">
  <strong>B1:</strong>
  <input id="b1" />
  <strong>B2:</strong>
  <input id="b2" />
  <strong>B3:</strong>
  <input id="b3" />
  <!--
    this triggers the same function but when clicked.
    you only need one of them, but I left both for reference.
  -->
  <input type="button" value="check" onclick="analyzeData()">
</form>
<div>
  <h1 id="result"></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I'm just a beginner. Sorry for the mistakes. I ran the code but it seems the adding up is not functioning properly. The result if b2 is greater than 3.5 only shows the answer of the first part.

For example:

b1 = 100
b2 = 5
b3 = 3000
The result should be: 76.362

Now it is 25.962

Comment: Yes, you're right. Please test it again. Something was really off - the problem was your number format (I wrote `1,4`, while it should have been `.`). I mostly just copied and pasted your formula and adapted it into JavaScript, but I missed that one. That's one thing you should be aware: it seems in your location Excel uses `,` as a decimal separator - that is almost never true in programming, where the decimal separator is usually `.`.

Comment: I adapted the number formatting in your question (as it would be in English format, commas as decimal separators), just to make the adaption a little clearer.

Comment: Wow! thank you so much. One last question. The outcome is in full euro's. Is it possible to round to whole euros? Like this with a point between the thousands and hundreds  €25.962

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible! Could you please update that info into your question? I'll be back in a couple hours and I'll edit accordingly (just so that it's clear that the rounding was a requirement).

Comment: I made the edits using the Dutch default number formatting, plus a small explanation above the snippet. Check out if that's what you meant.

Comment: Great! This was exactly what I meant. Thank you so much!